# rospy subscriber queue

Tags: ros, rospy, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm writing an ekf by myself as a project in a lecture and I thing I have a problem with the queue of the callback function to update the odometry. The thing is that I subscribe the topic odom as:

```
 rospy.Subscriber("odom", Odometry, odometryUpdate)
```

but it does not has queue. I've checked [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers) to see if there is any option of adding a queue in rospy, but I can not find it.
Is it possible to add a queue? If so, how can it be done?

if it is not possible to add a queue I would like to give more than just one parameter to the function odometryUpadte (the call back function). How can I do this?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30534/rospy-subscriber-queue/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can check the API here:

http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Subscriber-class.html

There you can see that you can define a queue size for you subscriber.

Hope that helps

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use queue_size (in hydro at least):

```
rospy.Subscriber("joy", Joy, callback, queue_size=1)
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2014-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1